# Share user session between SPA (subdomain) and API in main domain

Tags: php, api, session, token, single-page-application

I'm working in an SPA (single page app), witch my idea is to deploy it in app.mydomain.com, and the thing is when a make a request to the API (CakePHP3 in mydomain.com) I cannot get data from authenticated user (if there is one).

I think I have two options, share session between domains, or use an user_token to make an authenticated call, but i'm not sure how it's works.

Any ideas / recomendations?

Regards!

Comment: please provide some code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend to use an "user_token". You could add an authentication endpoint to your API where the user sends the credentials and the endpoint returns an JWT. Then you should include this JWT in every subsequently request to your API (in the Authorization header). The API can then validate the request based on the JWT. In PHP there are already some good libraries to create and validate an JWT. If you have the time you should also take a look at OAuth2.